# How do I create a string with Quotes in it in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, variables

C# newbie here.  I am trying to set a C# variable as follows.

```
string profileArg = @"/profile ""eScore"" ";
```

The end result is that I want the variable to contain the value

```
/profile "eScore"
```

There should be a space in the string after the "eScore"

How do I do it?

Seth

Comment: I'm confused by your question, `string profileArg = @"/profile ""eScore"" ";` seems to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Maybe you don't see the trailing space because it is blank :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have a space after eScore in your string.

```
// a space after "eScore"
string profileArg = @"/profile ""eScore"" ";

// no space after "eScore"
string profileArg = @"/profile ""eScore""";

// space in "eScore "
string profileArg = @"/profile ""eScore """;

// No space using escaping
string profileArg = "/profile \"eScore\"";
```

Answer (score 14):

You appear to already be doing that correctly.

Answer (score 3):

```
string profileArg = "/profile \"eScore\" ";
```

Comment: The backslash isn't used for escaping in a verbatim string (@ makes it verbatim) use a double "" instead (like VB.)

Answer (score 2):

```
string profileArg = "/profile \"eScore\" ";
```

Answer (score 2):

2 options:

- normal backslashed escaped: "This is a test of \"Quotes\"."
- @ string double escaped: @"This is a test of ""Quotes""."

both of these should contain the same string:

```
This is a test of "Quotes".
```

Answer (score 2):

One possibility would be

```
string profileArg = "/profile \"eScore\" ";
```

To me this looks clearer than the verbatim literal

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string profileArg = "/profile \"eScore\" ";
```

You want to put `\"` for any literal double quotes.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to leave the @ sign.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the others . . . The `@` sign that precedes the first quote tells C# to not interpret the backslash `\` as an escape character.  That's why the examples given omit the `@` sign.  Then you can use the `\"` to put in the quotation marks.